# JPA Scheme Listener, is there such thing?

Tags: jpa

you can tell hibernate or any JPA implementation to create the scheme for you, the question is what if you want to populate table with a default initial records ?.

for a solution, at application startup you can check if the table is empty and then create records, but i think if there is a listener called after scheme creation that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate, you can create an `import.sql` (in src/main/resources for example) file with your initial data. At application startup, the file is picked up and executed by Hibernate.

You can also use a specialized tool to prefill (and empty) the DB, like [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) or [Arquillian perstistence extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence).

As for the original question - AFAIK you have only acces to [Entity lifecycle events](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) in JPA. Theoretically they can be used to check or alter the contents of the table, but this is a bad idea.

EDIT : There is no accessible JPA standard for DB seeding. Even the [Pro JPA 2 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219564) advises seeding with a JDBC setup. I think you are better off with the aforementioned tools. I am not aware of any seeding assistance for EclipseLink like Hibernate's `import.sql`, but there is [some DIY advice for a similar workaround](http://onpersistence.blogspot.de/2010/03/running-sql-script-on-startup-in.html). I hope it'll help.

Comment: but this is not a JPA standard, am i right? and what about eclipse link

Answer (score 1):

In EclipseLink you can use a SessionEventListener to receive an event when a persistence unit starts up.

You can set a SessionEventListener using the persistence unit property, "eclipselink.session-event-listener"
You can use the postLogin event to populate your tables, or execute your own DDL.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/SessionEventAdapter.html